# mysqli class joshcam error in insert function

Tags: php, php-mysqlidb

I am using [joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class) library and I am getting error in insert function while I am trying to insert data using an array
Error message: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::getSubQuery() in ../MysqliDb.php on line 548.
Will anybody tell me how to fix it?

My code is here

```
 $db->where("project_id", $data_project['project_id']);
                   $tmp = $db->getOne("projects");
               if(count($tmp))
                    {
                        $data = array(  "project_name" => $data_project['project_name'],
                                        "project_url" => $data_project['project_url'],
                                        "project_details" => $data_project['project_details']
                        );
                        $db->where('project_id', $data_project['project_id']);
                        $id = $db->update('projects',$data);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $data = array("project_id" => $data_project['project_id'],
                                        "user_id" => 1,
                                        "project_name" => $data_project['project_name'],
                                        "project_url" => $data_project['project_url'],`enter code here`
                                        "project_details" => $data_project['project_details']
                        );
                        $id = $db->insert('projects',$data);
```

Comment: Probably it is an old version of that library? get the latest code from github because I see some changes..

Comment: I tried it with latest class but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: you must add your php code in order to debug it.. I think that your array contains an SimpleXMLElement ...

Comment: See my code. I am not using xml its very simple

Comment: I added code in my question